# rewriterule to redirect

Tags: rewrite

I want to redirect `test.example.com/cgi-bin/abc.sh` to `test1.abc.com/cgi-bin/abc.sh`, but it is not redirecting. My rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://test1.abc.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirecting `test.example.com/abc` to `test1.abc.com/abc` is working fine. Should I be required to add another RewriteRule or RewriteCond to include cgi-bin (because of ScriptAlias or something)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put .htaccess inside cgi-bin folder as well to solve this problem.